# ListView won't scroll in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I try to create a scrollable ListView, but for somes reasons it's not working.

My goal: create a ListView connected to Firebase. My ListView gather well datas, but scoll is impossible.

The body of my Scaffold:

```dart
body: const SingleChildScrollView(
  child: RecipesInformations(),
),
```

My widget:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _recipesStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Chargement recettes");
        }

        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            List tags = List.from(document["tags"]);

            return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF011200)),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 32, left: 16, right: 16, top: 8),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          data["title"],
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          softWrap: false,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ));
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Let me know if you need more informations.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72790095/edit) and include the screenshot of what you're having now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `SingleChildScrollView` might help.

Answer (score 0):

In you `ListView`constructor, set `primary: false` since you are nesting it inside of a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) to simplify things and remove unnecessary nested scrollviews. Something like this could work:

```
body: RecipesInformations(),
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _recipesStream,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
...
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final document = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
          return Container(
            ...
          );
        },
      ) 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) instead of [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

[From the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), the `StreamBuilder` is a *Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Stream.* So, only the last item is going to show up on the screen.

Instead, transform the stream to a List with the [`toList()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/toList.html) method and use it on the `FutureBuilder.future` property like so:

```dart
    ...

    return FutureBuilder<List<QuerySnapshot>>(
      future: _recipesStream.toList(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {

    ...
```

`snapshot.data` now is a `List` of `QuerySnapshot`. So, it's going to be a bit different to iterate over it:

```dart
      ...

      return ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: snapshot.data!.map((query) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = query.docs.first;

      ...
```

The result is going to be something like this:

[image]